# No Output or Input Device Detected in Elementary OS

Tags: audio

So, two or three days ago, i installed **Elementary OS** and everything was going good, but when today i turned it on and i found there was no audio coming out, and found the message saying "**No Output Device Detected**" in my Audio Settings and exactly the similar case for the input device.[image: Screenshot] 
So,i was wondering what could possibly goes wrong all of sudden. Please Help Me!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a Dell XPS 13 9343.

Comment: I installed twice Elementary on dual boot (win10) a week ago and got the same problem. I could't make it recognize my laptop speakers or headphones (HP Omen).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too after a system update.  Relogging fixed it.